# How to upload a file to document library in SharePoint online using REST APIs

Tags: sharepoint-online, java

We have a requirement to upload a file to SharePoint Online using REST APIs. When I try to open 'https://{site}/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx', in order to generate an access token to authorize REST API calls to the SharePoint site to retrieve data and manipulate the site data, I get the below message even though I have admin access:

**Sorry, you don't have access.**

I got to know that the user must be a site collection administrator in order to have access to this page.
However, with my company SharePoint site, I don't see an option to add user as a site collection administrator. And also, I don't see an Admin icon in the top left under the Apps section. Instead, I have a Partner icon which is not accessible.
Can someone help me what are the necessary permissions or licenses required inorder to work with SharePoint REST APIs?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant a user with Site Collection Administrator through SharePoint Admin Center or Site Settings at the root of a Site Collection.

- https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-make-user-site-collection-administrator/

Also, you can register app on Azure AD to perform auth flow to access SharePoint rest API:

- https://www.advaiya.com/blog/access-sharepoint-rest-api-using-oauth/

BR